# How to read OData Batch Response with the generic OData client?

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I am trying to perform a batch read request with the generic OData client. The result works, however I have the feeling that it can be done better. But I have this one understanding questions.

I took the example from the doc and converted it a bit, since I want to have multiple reads in one batch..obviously. So my first request looks like this:

```java
String servicePath = "/sap/opu/odata4/sap/zservice/srvd/sap/zservice/0001/";
String entityName = "Product";
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientAccessor.getHttpClient(httpDestination);

ODataRequestBatch requestBatch = new ODataRequestBatch(servicePath, ODataProtocol.V4);

products.forEach(p -> {
  StructuredQuery query = StructuredQuery.onEntity("Product", ODataProtocol.V4);
  query.select("ProductCategory", "Product", "Price");

  query.filter(FieldReference.of("ProductCategory").equalTo(category),
  FieldReference.of("Product").equalTo(p));
  String encodedQuery = query.getEncodedQueryString();

  ODataRequestRead request = new ODataRequestRead(servicePath, entityName, encodedQuery,
  ODataProtocol.V4);
  requestBatch.addRead(request);
});

ODataRequestResultMultipartGeneric batchResult = requestBatch.execute(httpClient);
```

Now comes the part where I am unsure how to read the result. According to the documentation the following is done, which if fine, as long as I have just one read.

```java
// extract information from batch response, by referring to the individual OData request reference
ODataRequestResultGeneric queryResult = batchResult.getResult(request);
List<Map<String, Object>> listOfEntityFields = queryResult.asListOfMaps();
```

In my example though, I have a loop and the variable `request` is unreachable/always different.

I now go the way that I have the result using the method `batchResult.getBatchedResponses()` the httpReposonses output, read me here the answers, make a JSONObject from it and then work with the results. But somehow I can't get rid of the feeling that I'm missing something here. Can you possibly help me on the hint?

Comment: Why are you using the generic OData client though, instead of the type-safe OData client: https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/odata/v4-vdm-client#execute-batch-request?
As your read request is pretty straightforward, using the typed client makes your code much more readable and provides more convenience for response parsing.

Comment: The other side unfortunately does not manage to generate reasonable services, so the metadata is not correct and the generator does not generate working clients..Typical project work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list to store the request elements and then iterate over the request elements to get the results.

```java
List<ODataRequestRead> readRequests = new ArrayList<>();
products.forEach(p -> {
  ...

  ODataRequestRead request = new ODataRequestRead(servicePath, entityName, encodedQuery,ODataProtocol.V4);
  readRequests.add(request);
  requestBatch.addRead(request);
  ...
});

readRequests.forEach(request -> {
            final ODataRequestResultGeneric result = batchResult.getResult(request);
});
```